# cannot find User after runing new-spuser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, groups

I have used following PS Script to add a user to a group on a web. I didn't any error but I cannot find the user in the group or anywhere else. Thanks for your advice.

```
New-SPUser "wm\test2" -Web "http://mydomain/sites/s1" -Group "reader on s1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `Set-SPUser -Identity 'fun/factory' -Web http://someserver -Group 'Name of group'`

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you need to do a web.Update after adding a user.

(I'm not a machine with SharePoint installed at the moment to test, sorry)

Comment: I run web.Update() still not working

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to get the user in PowerShell?

```
Get-SPUser "wm\test2" –Web "http://mydomain/sites/s1"
```

Furthermore, does the user already exist in your domain?

Comment: When I run your script I get userLogin and DisplayName with wm\test2, Yes the user is already exist in my domain.